# flet не отображает View

Tags: python, view, flet

Пишу программу на `flet`, но почему то страница перестала отображаться, не могу понять в чем проблема.

Код `main.py`: (сокр.)

```
from flet import (MainAxisAlignment, dropdown, Page, app),
#    CrossAxisAlignment, PagePlatform, FilePickerFileType,
#    FilePicker)

import views
#import extra
import database as db
from api import (api)#, disconnect_errors, convert_place,
#    convert_group, convert_type)

button_style = views.button_style
center = MainAxisAlignment.CENTER

class Data:
    '''local data variables'''
    data = {'do':'', 'data':{}, 'user_id':0, 'task_id':0, 'cust_id':0, 'store_id':0, 'user_place':3}
data = Data()

def main(page: Page):
    def route_change(e):
        del e
        page.views.clear()

        if page.route == '/':
            view_sign = views.Sign()

            def go_main(e):
                del e
                data.data['do'] = 'checkSign'
                data.data['data']['login'] = view_sign.login.value
                data.data['data']['password'] = view_sign.password.value
                data.data['data']['rem'] = view_sign.rem.value
                page.go('/main')

            autosign = db.signin()
            if autosign:
                data.data['user_id'] = autosign[2]
                data.data['user_place'] = api.user_place(data.data['user_id'])
                data.data['data']['login'] = autosign[0]
                data.data['do'] = 'AutoSign'
                page.go('/main')
            else:
                page.views.append(view_sign.view(go_main))


    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.go(page.route)
    page.update()



app(target=main, assets_dir='assets/')
```

`views.py`: (сокр.)

```
from flet import (ButtonStyle, RoundedRectangleBorder, SnackBar,
    Text, TextField, Checkbox, Container, Column, Row, View,
    margin, padding, BoxShadow, alignment, MainAxisAlignment,
    CrossAxisAlignment, Image, ElevatedButton)#, border, icons,
#    FontWeight, ProgressBar, Dropdown, KeyboardType,
#    IconButton, Divider, dropdown)

button_style = ButtonStyle(shape=RoundedRectangleBorder(radius=10),
    bgcolor='#00a0e3', color='white')
snackbar_timeout = SnackBar(Text('Ошибка подключения к интернету! Перезайдите...'))
class Sign:
    '''view of "/" path'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.login = TextField(bgcolor='gray', max_lines=1, label='Логин', border_radius=10)
        self.password = TextField(bgcolor='gray', password=True,
            max_lines=1, can_reveal_password=True, label='Пароль', border_radius=10)
        self.rem = Checkbox(label='Запомнить меня', value=True)
    def view(self, go_main):
        """view data
        Args:
            go_main (func): go_main function

        Returns:
            View: view data
        """
        return View(
            route='/',
            controls=[
                Container(
                    margin=margin.all(-10),
                    height=90,
                    padding=padding.only(bottom=30),
                    bgcolor='#00a0e3',
                    shadow=BoxShadow(
                        spread_radius=0.8,
                        blur_radius=10
                    ),
                    alignment=alignment.top_center
                ),
                Container(
                    Column(
                        [
                            Container(
                                Row(
                                    [
                                        Image('/logo.jpg', height=150, width=280)
                                    ],
                                    alignment=MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                                    vertical_alignment=CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER
                                ),
                                padding=padding.only(bottom=15)
                            ),
                            Container(
                                Column(
                                    [
                                        self.login,
                                        self.password,
                                        self.rem
                                    ],
                                ),
                                padding=padding.only(left=20, right=20)
                            ),
                            Container(
                                ElevatedButton(text='Вход', scale=1.5,
                                    height=30, width=140,
                                    style=button_style, on_click=go_main),
                                alignment=alignment.center,
                                padding=padding.only(top=20)
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                )
            ],
            spacing=30, alignment=alignment.top_center
        )
```

Выдает просто пустой экран, другие страницы тоже не отображаются, что не так?